# Threadsafe python deque to list conversion

Tags: python, list, python-multithreading, deque

I using a Python deque as the transfer mechanism in a producer->consumer design. The deque is limited to maxlen and thread #1 appends values to it at a fast rate. Thread #2 consumes the values slowly, in chunks, but as I want to accommodate timing variations from the hardware device I read the content of the deque as a list and then process it without popping. This means I end up with maxlen values always available to run my filters.

```
list_to_process = list(dq)
for item in list_to_process:
    # some processing
```

However, the deque documentation only guarantees that append and pop are thread safe. That makes me think that the list I am creating might change during the processing stage. Can anyone confirm if that is the case?

If so I think my best option is to make a deepcopy during a lock. All alternative suggestions very welcome.

Thanks

Ed

Comment: That first statement will grab a copy of all of the items in the deque, but of course all the items will stay in the deque.  That makes me nervous.  How do you clean up the deque?  How do you know what's safe to clean up?  In general, queue.Queue tends to be the best way to handle this kind of thing.  It is thread-safe, and it will block until something is available.

Comment: Hi Tim, so does the above line definitely make a proper copy? Not just a list of references to the objects in the deque? The deque is cleaned up by the producer function when it gets started and stopped, the consumer only knows if there are any items to process or not.

Comment: I realized later that I was unclear.  No, the list will be a set of references to the objects in the deque.  Here's my question.  Let's say there are 7 items in the deque.  Your filter runs, you grab pointers to those 7 items.  Now the producer adds 2 more items.  Now there are 9 items in the deque, 7 of which are in process, 2 of which will be ignored.  How is that cleaned up?  You really should rearchitect this to use a simple queue.  One in, one out, simple transfer of ownership.